# Xamarin.Forms Rounded Entry Stroke Color

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I implemented the rounded entry control and it works fine. I want to change the stroke color without using the implemented colors, i.e parse a color like "#ee1f00". I am trying to use **parsecolor** method but it does not work. Below you will find my code. Thanks in advance.

```
 public class RoundedEntryAndroid : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            var gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
            gradientDrawable.SetCornerRadius(30f);
            gradientDrawable.SetStroke(5, Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor(Constants.primaryColor));
            gradientDrawable.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
            Control.SetBackground(gradientDrawable);

            Control.SetPadding(50, Control.PaddingTop, Control.PaddingRight,
                Control.PaddingBottom);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `Constants.primaryColor`?  Are you using all caps for the hex values?

Comment: @Jason "#ee1c26"

Comment: again, try using "#EE1C26"

Comment: @Jason did not work :(

Comment: what does "not work" mean?  Is it giving an error or exception?  Is it just failing silently?  If you use some fixed color instead of ParseColor does it work?

Comment: @Jason no exception appears but it does not view the color. And yes if I use for example Android.Graphics.Color.Black the stroke color changes

Comment: @Sam I use your code to test, the Entry border color change by using `gradientDrawable.SetStroke(5, Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#EE1C26"));`

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT it worked thanks to Jason. I was putting the stroke color like the background color :) . Thank u guys